# Login multiple users on same device to ParseServer using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, pfuser, parse-server

I am using `ParseServer` on the server side and the Parse iOS SDK on the client side. Here is what currently happens:

1. `userA` logs in (via `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground`)
2. On the server a `_Session` object gets created for `userA` (so `userA` is now logged in)
3. `userB` logs in (via same method, without first calling any 'logout' for `userA`)
4. On the server the `_Session` object for `userA` is gone, and there is now a `_Session` object for `userB`. So `userA` has been logged out, `userB` has been logged in.

What I would like to be able to do is to log-in `userA` AND `userB` at the same time (from the same device and app). If the first `_Session` was not getting automatically deleted, then I would be able to use the `sessionToken` (which I can save upon login) to change the `PFUser.currentUser` (using `PFUser.becomeInBackground`) between `userA` and `userB` as needed. But I need `ParseServer` to not delete the first `_Session`.

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this and talking to another developer (who had posted about the same issue elsewhere) - it seems like Parse simply won't work properly in the case described above.

The solution we are going for in the end is to save user credentials (using Keychain) and log-in users each time as needed (without the user having to re-type passwords all the time).